# Why is there a mirror image effect in the absorbance and fluorescence spectra?

Tags: physical-chemistry, biochemistry, absorption, fluorescence

I've read some answers online but I still can't seem to understand the mirror image effect. Why is the highest energy absorption (v" = 0 to v' = 4) the lowest energy fluorescence (v' = 4 to v" = 0)? Shouldn't the molecule that absorbs the highest-energy light emit the highest-energy light?

[image]

Comment: Please look at [Jablonski diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jablonski_diagram) and, in particular, the second figure shown there. Then follow the links for Stokes shift and Kasha’s rule.

Comment: See the answer here https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/134675/why-do-some-molecules-show-non-symmetric-absorption-and-emission-bands/134699#134699

Comment: @porphyrin Thanks for the help, I still don't understand why the highest energy absorption would have the lowest energy fluorescence. Am I missing something here?